# Url re-writing regular expression

Tags: asp.net, regex, url-rewriting

Using ASP.NET, and trying to implement friendly url re-writing but I'm having a heck of a time working with the  regular expression. Basically, I'm checking the url directly following the domain to see whether it is using the french-canadian culture, or whether it is a number - and not a number followed by characters. I need to catch anything that begins with 'fr-ca' OR a number, and both scenarios can have a trailing '/' (forward slash), but that's all...

fr-ca - GOOD
fr-ca/ - GOOD
fr-ca/625 - GOOD
fr-ca/gd - BAD
fr-ca43/ - BAD

1234 - GOOD
1234/ - GOOD
1234/g - GOOD
1234g - BAD
1g34 - BAD

This is what I've come up with : ^(fr-ca)?/?([0-9]+)?
But it doesn't seem to be working the way I want.. so I started fresh and came up with (^fr-ca)|(^[0-9]), which still isn't working the way I want. Please...HELP!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no idea about Asp.net, but the regexp was tested with grep. you could try in your .net box:

```
kent$  cat a
fr-ca
fr-ca/
fr-ca/625
fr-ca/gd
fr-ca43/
1234
1234/
1234/g
1234g
1g34
```

**updated**

```
kent$  grep -P "(^fr-ca$|^\d+$|^(fr-ca|\d+)/(\w|\d*)$)" a
fr-ca
fr-ca/
fr-ca/625
1234
1234/
1234/g
```

--

well this may not be the best regex, but would be the most straightforward one.

it matchs string

```
^fr-ca$
or ^\d+$
or ^(fr-ca|\d+)/(\w|\d*)$

the above line can be broken down as well
  ^(fr-ca|\d+)/(\w|\d*)$ :

starting with fr-ca or \d+
then comes "/"
after "/" we expect \w or \d*
then $(end)
```

Comment: is it possible to explain the regex really quickly ??

Comment: explanation was in updated answer, well I just want to wrap them in the code tag. so update the answer again.

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
^(fr-ca(?:\/\d*)?|[0-9]+(\/[a-zA-Z]*)?)$
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2uodh), it matches all your good cases and not the bad ones.

Answer (score 1):

Probably can try...

`^(fr-ca|\d).*$`

But of course this a regex to match the entire string (as it has the end-of-sting `$` anchor). Are you wanting to pull out multiple matches?

In light of re-reading the post :)

`^(fr-ca|\d+)(\/\d+|\/)?$`

Comment: 1234gg passes for that expression, which it shouldn't!

Comment: "I need to catch anything that begins with 'fr-ca' OR a number" :)

Comment: "and both scenarios can have a trailing '/' (forward slash), but that's all..." ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
^(\d+(\/\w*)?)$|^(fr-ca\/\d+)$|^(fr-ca\/?)$
```

This worked for me for all of your examples. I'm not sure your intention for using this regex so I don't know if it is capturing exactly what you want to capture.